# function to capture 3 last bits of the decimal representation

Tags: python, math, bit, representation

taking only the lower 3 digits of decimal data? Any python math function library do the job

```
data = 55554343.345
incoming(data)



def incoming(data)
   in_data = data
```

I need to collect the last 3 bit of my decimal data to be like: in_data = 343.345

Comment: Do you want the result as a string or as a float?  (Is this for reporting purposes, or do you need to do further computation with the truncated result?)

Comment: I need to do further computation

Comment: If you want the result as a float, then @ArunGhosh's answer should work.  Yes, you're getting a result that's out by some tiny amount.  Is an error of one billionth really an issue in your application?  If so, why?

Answer (score 2):

Get the reminder of division by 1000

```
def incoming(data)
   in_data = round(data % 1000,3)
```

Comment: Are you sure this works ? I mean he wants only three places after the decimal but your code outputs `343.344999999`

Comment: i need 343.345, not expanding the floating fraction part, .34499999

Comment: thanks Arun. my point is with putting round(data % 1000,3). It may ended up rounding after being expanding. if the value is originally, 343.34, the fraction of .34 is not produced from the rounding function. I need to keep the fraction intact

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sammy :)

```
data = 1411984956.155
incoming(data)

def incoming(incoming_data)
   in_da = str(incoming_data)
   print 'incoming data', float(in_da[7:])
```

result:

```
incoming data 956.155
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution!  Try it with `55554343.345` (the value you used in the question).

Comment: for 55554343.345, i need to put print 'incoming data', float(in_da[5:]), that's the best i could get. if you have any better way, please let me know